# Redirecionar parâmetros .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Gostaria de saber como redirecionar uma url com parâmetros no `.htaccess` . Eu tenho uma URL que pode receber diversos parâmetros e quero redirecioná-la para outra página com estes parâmetros.

A página é `wp-login.php`, tenho que redirecionar para a página `/login/`. Mas preciso redirecionar todos os parâmetros, não apenas a página.
ex:

```
http://site.com/wp-login.php?para=ola
http://site.com/login?para=ola

http://site.com/wp-login.php
http://site.com/login



RewriteRule ^/wp-login.php$ /login [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Tem uma quantidade absurda de perguntas sobre isso aqui no site, veja qual te ajuda melhor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%20amigavel%20htaccess

Comment: O redirecionamento assim é interno, quer redirecionar ou reescrever as urls? Se for reescrever da maneira que fez já envia os parametros GET normalmente. Explique melhor qual o problema ocorre.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  Eu gostaria de redirecionar, mas a URL login, tem que receber os parametros que tinham na outra URL... Pois, se tiver parametros, ele não redireciona... eu tenho que redirecionar tudo... e enviar os parametros de um para o outro...

Comment: Olha eu acho que talvez você esteja confundindo o termo redirecionar, vamos por partes, você quer que quando acesse `/wp-login.php` mostre o conteudo de `/login` né?

Comment: Eu tenho o wordpress. A pagina de login é: wp-login.php... criei uma outra página chamada de /login/ , preciso redirecionar a primeira para esta...  pois da maneira que fiz acima ele não redireciona quando tem os parâmetros e nem envia os parametros para a outra página...

Comment: @abcd deve escrever isso na pergunta, e outra o exemplo que adicionou não ficou claro, você misturou no meio do código, veja perguntas que tem pontuação alta pra ver como as pessoas escrevem e escrever melhor as suas proprias, entenda como uma critica construtiva. Estou respondendo a sua pergunta.

Comment: @abcd ele pode estar enviando sim, o problema pode ser no seu formulário também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sinceramente não estou entendendo, nada mais esta funcionando, nem a maneira que descrevi e nem as sua...

Comment: Como eu disse e torno a repetir, duas coisas: Ou você não entendeu a diferença de redirecionamento e reescrita, ou o problema é no seu formulário (a parte HTML sabe?) ou então um terceiro, o .htaccess não esta no lugar correto ou você não esta usando Apache, falta muita informação pra determinar a causa do teu problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Existe algo no wordpress que esta me atrapalhando realizar o que eu desejo. A solução foi utilizar funções do próprio wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é redirecionamento mesmo, que é diferente de reescrita, a maneira que fez o .htaccess ele só serve para quando acessar:

```
http://exemplo/wp-login.php?teste=1
```

Irá exibir o conteudo de:

```
/wp-login.php?teste=1
```

Para redirecionamentos mesmo, aonde vai mudar o URL no navegador, você precisar usar a *flag* `R=` conforme a documentação https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Outra coisa a regex as vezes tem que escapar alguns caracteres como `.` e `-`, também não se deve começar com `/`, você também pode ter esquecido o `RewriteEngine On`, deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp\-login\.php$ login [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Se `/login` é uma pasta faça assim pra evitar mais de um redirecionamento:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp\-login\.php$ login/ [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Testei aqui e funcionou com GET.

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada por mim e que funcionou no wordpress, foi a utilização de funções nativas. pois no .htaccess não deu certo:

```
add_action('init','custom_login');

function custom_login(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
        wp_redirect('login');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas isso não envia a querystring, se o seu código funcionou assim é porque o problema é outro e você não soube explicar amigo. Entenda como uma critica construtiva ok? Até mais

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente não envia... Mas pelo que andei analisando, é desnecessário o envio da query, pois no plugin faz automáticamenteo redirecionamento para a página desejada... Mas deu certo o código acima... Obrigado e até a próxima... ATT